# Can I be sure that the binary code of the functions will be copied sequentially?

Tags: c++, c, reverse-engineering

Sorry if this question already exist, because I hope this approach is used but i just don't know how this called. So, my purpose to execute sequence of functions from memory, for this I copied size of first and last func.

This is my first try:

```
source.cpp

void func1(int var1, int var2)
{
  func2();
  func3();
  //etc.
}
void func2(...){...}
void func3(...){...}
void funcn(){return 123;}//last func as border, I do not use it

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

main.cpp

#include"source.cpp"

long long size= (long long)funcn-(long long)func1;// i got size of binary code of this funcs;
// and then i can memcpy it to file or smth else and execute by adress of first
```

Firstly it's worked correct, but after updating my functions it's crashed. Size has become negative.
Then i tried to attach it to memory hardlier:

```
source.cpp

extern void(*pfunc1)(int, int);
extern void(*pfuncn)();

void(*pfunc1)(int , int) = &func1;
void(*funcn)() = &funcn;

static void __declspec(noinline) func1(int var1, int var2)
{
 //the same impl
}
static void __declspec(noinline) func2(...){...}
static void __declspec(noinline) func3(...){...}
static void __declspec(noinline) funcn(...){retunr 123;}

//////////////////////////////////
main.cpp
#include"source.cpp"

long long size= (long long) pfuncn - (long long) pfunc1;
//same impl
```

This worked after my 1st update, but then, I had to update it again, and now this gives me wrong size. Size was  near 900+ bytes. I changed some funcs, and size become 350+ bytes i haven't changed that many.
I disabled optimizations and inline optimizations.

So my question is how to be sure that my func1 will be less adress then last funcn and what could change their locations in memory. Thank you  for attention.

Comment: There is no guarantee that func1 through funcn will be adjacent in memory, let alone that they are present in the final binary. Anyway, this seems like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). What do you need this for?

Comment: pointer arithmetic between unrelated objects in undefined behavior.  The fact that you had to had to use a c-style cast should make you pause, as they don't care about the language rules.

Comment: If there a reason you don't use an array of function pointers?

Comment: Neither C nor C++ guarantees you that a pointer to a function actually contains in any form the address where the code of the function is (it could be the address of a function handle or other data structured used to access the function) or that the code of one function is in one contiguous segment of memory, let alone that different functions are contiguous. Do not write code like this. Whatever you are trying to accomplish, this is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: I get size of this funcs, copy it in memory and then call it in allocated memory and then call by adress of allocation. Should i edit my question in some way to avoid XY problem?

Comment: Please explain _why_ you want to copy machine code around. Are you trying to write a just-in-time compiler or something like that?

Comment: @zwol for example to copy the code from FLASH memory to the SRAM. Why? To minimize the interrupt latency, to implemet the bootloader (when you need to erase the flash) and many other use cases. Not everyone is Linux or OS centric

Comment: Good question, well written, and potentially useful to others.

Comment: @P__J__ That's certainly another possibility.  I would like to hear what Stanislav's answer to the question is, though.

Comment: @zwol I am just interested in creation something like cryptor. This approache needed for load PE header for execution program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC family only!

You can force the compiler to put the whole function to separate section. Then you can know the memory area where the funcion resides.

```
int __attribute__((section(".foosection"))) foo()
{
    /* some code here */
}
```

in linker script in the .text you need to add

```
 .text :
  {
 
      /* ... */

    __foosection_start = .;
     *(*foosection)
     *(.foosection*) 
     __foosection_end = .;

     /* .... */
```

and in the place where you want to know or use it

```
extern unsigned char __foosection_start[];
extern unsigned char __foosection_end[];

void printfoo()
{
    printf("foosection start: %p, foosection end: %p\n ", (void *)__foosection_start, (void *)__foosection_end);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// and then i can memcpy it to file or smth else and execute by adress of first
```

> copy it in memory and then call it in allocated memory and then call by adress of allocation.

This needs to be stated:

**You cannot copy code from one location to another and hope for it to work.**

1. There's no guarantees that all the code required to call a function
   be located in a contiguous block.
2. There's no guarantee the function pointer actually point to the
   beginning of the needed code.
3. There's no guarantees you can effectively write to executable memory. To the OS, you'd look a lot like a virus.
4. there's no guarantees the code is relocatable (able to work after being moved to a different location). for this it requires to use only relative addresses

In short: unless you have supporting tools that go beyond the scope of standard C++, don't even think about it.

Comment: `In short: don't even think about it.` Not the truth. Very ofen used in the embedded development. For example to copy code from FLASH to SRAM and to execute it from there. So programmer should think about it and know how to archieve it

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not possible because of a requirement you did not mention, but why not use an array of function pointers?

```
std::function<void()> funcs[] = {
    func2,
    func3,
    [](){ /* and an inline lambda, because why not */ },
};

// Call them in sequence like so: 
for (auto& func: funcs) {
   func();
}
```

Comment: I will use memcpy of this functions in other project by allocation memory and call first func from adress of allocation. So this array of pointers will be wrong. What should i change in my question to avoid missunderstoding? Thank you